# VB to C# string translation

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, compiler-errors

I have some visual basic code:

```
       Dim jsScript As String = <js><![CDATA[
document.all("q").value = "stack overflow";
document.all("search_button_homepage").click();
                             ]]></js>.Value
   browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScriptB)
```

That executes a string as javascript into Cefsharp browser. So I want to translate this into C#, and I do this:

```
string jscriptB = <js><![CDATA[
document.all("q").value = "stack overflow";
document.all("search_button_homepage").click();
                             ]]></js>.Value
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScriptB)
```

And I get a whole bunch of error messages, such as:

Error   CS0103  The name 'document' does not exist in the current context

Invalid expression term '<'

Can someone explain what is happening and how to fix it? I can't imagine why a simple string conversion doesn't work. Thank you for your time and have a great day.

edit:
So I now have:

```
 var test = @"< js >< ![CDATA[
  document.all(""q"").value = ""stack overflow"";
            document.all(""search_button_homepage"").click();
                             ]]></ js >.Value";
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(test);
```

But it doesn't execute the javascript like the vb code did. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: C# doesn't support xml literals like vb. Instead of the xml use a verbatim string literal (without the cdata) by prepending the string with an `@`: `var script = @"document.all('q').value =...." ` It supports line breaks as well (enter key). For double quotes you need to escape with a second  double quote `@"there's a ""quote"" here"`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 your solution got rid of the error messages but now the javascript doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# doesn't have VB's xml literal feature, so you have to call the XElement.Parse method yourself:

```
string jsScript = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("<js><![CDATA[ document.all(\"q\").value = \"stack overflow\"; document.all(\"search_button_homepage\").click(); ]]></js>").Value;
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsScriptB);
```